# ElasticSearch query with conditions on multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have data of this format in elasticsearch, each one is in seperate document:

{ 'pid': 1, 'nm' : 'tom'}, { 'pid': 1, 'nm' : 'dick''},{ 'pid': 1, 'nm' : 'harry'}, { 'pid': 2, 'nm' : 'tom'}, { 'pid': 2, 'nm' : 'harry'}, { 'pid': 3, 'nm' : 'dick'}, { 'pid': 3, 'nm' : 'harry'}, { 'pid': 4, 'nm' : 'harry'}

```
    {
       "took": 137,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "hits": {
          "total": 8,
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KS86AaDUbQTYUmwY",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 1,
                   "nm": "Harry"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KJ9BAaDUbQTYUmwW",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 1,
                   "nm": "Tom"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KRlbAaDUbQTYUmwX",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 1,
                   "nm": "Dick"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KYnKAaDUbQTYUmwa",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 2,
                   "nm": "Harry"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KXL5AaDUbQTYUmwZ",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 2,
                   "nm": "Tom"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KbcpAaDUbQTYUmwb",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 3,
                   "nm": "Dick"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9Kdy5AaDUbQTYUmwc",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 3,
                   "nm": "Harry"
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "query_test",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "AVj9KetLAaDUbQTYUmwd",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                   "pid": 4,
                   "nm": "Harry"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

And I need to find the pid's which have 'harry' and do not have 'tom', which in the above example are 3 and 4. Which essentialy means look for the documents having same pids where none of them has nm with value 'tom' but at least one of them have nm with value 'harry'.

How do I query that?

**EDIT**: Using Elasticsearch version 5

Comment: were u able to solve for this?

Answer (score 1):

What if you have a `POST` request body which could look something like below, where you might use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) :

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "nm" : "harry" }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "term" : { "nm" : "tom" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use a term query on a field which is analyzed ? nm would be analyzed in that case if no mapping provided.

Comment: @Artholl what if you're using `not_analyzed`, if you don't want that field to be analyzed for the above scenario ?

Comment: @Kulasangar  wouldn't this query apply the match/filter conditions on the same document? But here, for example, three documents have the same pid ie 1, but three different values for 'nm'.

Comment: @harbinger This would get applied to all the documents, but in the above sample we're matching the field `nm` in order to filter it out. Did the above sample work out in your scenario ?

Comment: @Kulasangar sure, this is the solution but I think this should be included in the answer. Nevertheless there could be an issue with the match in that case. A mapping with one analyzed and one not analyzed fields for nm could be a nice addition to the answer.

Comment: @Artholl yes you're right. Thank you and +1 for pointing it out. I've edited the answer :)

Comment: @Kulasangar  Filtered and not is deprecated in es5. So I used bool and must_not. No it did not work.

Comment: What're you getting if you use must and must_not?

Comment: @harbinger i've updated the answer using the bool. try if it works?

Comment: All of the four documents.

Comment: @harbinger you mean after you did what I've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @Kulasangar   Yes. The code is querying the same document with both the conditions and all four docs with nm value 'Harry' passes. I have updated my question with what the data looks like in elasticsearch.

Comment: Aren't you expecting the results to show which only contains with nm=harry and which doesn't have nm=tom?

Comment: I don't think it will help as your query will work on each doc and not on bucket of pid. So all docs with nm = harry will pass.

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively very new in Elasticsearch, so I might be wrong. But I have never seen such query. Simple filters can not be used here as those are applied on a doc (and not aggregations) which you do not want. What I see is you want to do a "Group by" query with "Having" clause (in terms of SQL). But Group by queries involve some aggregation (like avg, max, min of any field) which is used in "Having" clause. Basically you use a reducer for Post processing of aggregation results. For queries like this **Bucket Selector Aggregation** can be used. Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

But your case is different. You do not want to apply Having clause on any metric aggregation but you want to check if some value is present in field (or column) of your "group by" data. In terms of SQL, you want to do a "where" query in "group by".  This is what I have never seen. You can also read [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110)

However, at application level, you can easily do this by breaking your query. First find unique pid where nm= harry using term aggs. Then get docs for those pid with additional condition nm != tom.

 P.S. I am very new to ES. And I will be very happy if any one contradicts me show ways to do this in one query. I will also learn that.